# Something is limiting my bandwidth in Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, bandwidth

I believe some settings in Windows (registry, policy) is throttling my bandwidth to 200kilobytes/sec. 
A few weeks back I tried out a few applications (e.g. Netbalancer) and fiddled around with some settings (router, Windows) to limit bandwidth. I have since uninstalled them all, yet my bandwidth is still limited.

Possibilities:

1. router (I have ruled out as my other devices speed test at 500KB/s; also not limited when in linux)
2. hardware / wifi dongle (I have ruled out as when I boot into Linux, speed test is 500KB/s with same hardware)
3. applications (I have ruled out as starting Windows in safe mode it is still limited to 200KB/s)
4. Windows qos / policy setting (ruled out running gpresult shows no policies in place )

This leaves some other Windows setting/registry setting that is causing throttling.

What setting may be causing the limit to my bandwidth?

Comment: You have installed the software (which for all purposes is malware) and removed the limits.  Good idea to not use software only when you understand how it works and what it will modify

Comment: @Ramhound, i have installed the software with the intention and knowledge that they will limit the bandwidth. After their removal, i am still stuck with the limit, which being 200KB is very exact, so leads me to believe there is some windows /registry setting which i have changed and forgotten about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you where messing with settings/programs to limit bandwidth, the first thing I would do is double (or triple) check to make sure that there is nothing still preventing you from getting full speeds.
Specifically, check you make sure that there are no programs installed that may still be active on the Windows installation.

Otherwise, this sounds like it has to be a Windows driver issue.

Make sure that you are on the latest drivers for the chipset you are using. Also, make sure that all of the motherboard drivers are loaded. Sometimes Windows will automatically install drivers for you through Windows Update and they are not the best ones to use for performance.

Comment: New drivers through windows update, is actually a good idea i never thought of! Unfortunately I have subsequently updated to latest drivers per manufacturers site, and still no luck. Also loaded all motherboard drivers. Checked there is no programs installed. Not sure if there is still not a registry / windows setting still set somewhere though...

Comment: You were right, there was a remnant of some program still active. I ended up reinstalling all applications, then uninstalling them all again, and the limit was removed.